# Can't start MySQL in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

So I was trying to use this login system I made and it started giving me weird errors.  I figured out that it was because MySQL wasn't started.  So I tried to start it, but it wouldn't.  Here is the log:

```
10:06:12 PM [mysql] Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:06:12 PM [mysql] Status change detected: running
10:06:13 PM [mysql] Status change detected: stopped
10:06:13 PM [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:06:13 PM [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:06:13 PM [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method
10:06:13 PM [mysql] Check the "/xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log" file
10:06:13 PM [mysql] and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

And here is some of the more notable lines in the error log (mysql_error.log):

```
130318 22:06:12 InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
130318 22:06:12 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130318 22:06:13 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1599518
130318 22:06:13 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130318 22:06:13 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130318 22:06:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130318 22:06:13 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't 
                        find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
```

Can these errors be fixed without reinstalling XAMPP?

Comment: may be some other services may be using mysql port

Comment: don't have skype installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just reinstalled it and kept the htdocs folder.

Answer (score 7):

Opening the XAMPP Control Panel in Administrator mode and uninstalling the MySQL service and then reinstalling it back again worked for me. To do that, check and uncheck the circled checkbox in the provided snapshot. Here is the picture...[image: How to install & unstall the MySQL service]

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. I dont know why its the second time mysql service is automatically uninstalled after i shutdown my computer and come bakc to it the next day.

Comment: still showing this log

 [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
9:53:22 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

Answer (score 4):

Stop another Mysql server in Your computer. You can show it open TaskManager 
Stop or remove another servers and restart xammp

Comment: How do I "Stop or remove another servers and restart xammp".  I stopped the "taskhost.exe" things.  Is that it?  I also tried restarting my computer cause that would clear the process', right? Still doesn't work.

Comment: check your services named "mysql". check is it started or not? and check its path.. is it mysql from your xampp?

Comment: Theres nothing in the services called "mysql" and yes it is.

Answer (score 3):

Fixing the MySQL server not starting in XAMPP is done by reverting back the data files pre-issue.

Navigate to your XAMPP MySQL directory (C:\xampp\mysql).

Create a new folder called FIX_BACKUP.

Copy C:\xampp\mysql\backup and C:\xampp\mysql\data into C:\xampp\mysql\FIX_BACKUP.

Paste the contents of C:\xampp\mysql\backup into C:\xampp\mysql\data overwriting all the files.

Finally copy the ibdata1 file from C:\xampp\mysql\FIX_BACKUP\data into C:\xampp\mysql\data overwriting the file.

Your MySQL server should now start in the XAMPP control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed this problem and it worked for me, don't need to reinstall it.

1. Open your XAMPP and find Explorer.
2. Find and rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old.
3. Create a new folder mysql/data.
4. Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder.

5 Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to
mysql/data except the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders.

6. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside mysql/data folder.
7. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel and Problem-solved

And here are the links on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XH8wOgkSukk

Comment: Only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error but checking services showed a mysql service running so I stopped it and now it's working.  I did this through the XAMPP Control Panel running as Administrator and getting to services from there.